# Autopopulate Form-Fields from DB with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, auto-populate

i've a question and need your help
i have a empty form with about 10 input fields. all i want to do is :

if a user fill in the user's login name and hit the tab key - the other fields should be filled out with the related data stored in the database. like users location, email etc.

could some give me a cfml related example please?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to approach this:

- Use javascript to check for on tab event ( key press for the tab key )
- Call a cfc, passing the value of the input field to the cfc
- query the database for a field that matched exactly that data
- return the data as json and populate the rest of the fields.

Assuming you have basic javascript and cfml skills this would be the way I would approach this.

Comment: This is what I was going to mention also. I was putting together a Coldfusion mockup to make sure I had the steps correct.

Comment: I was able to put something together but don't have a mysql/sql table to run it on.

Comment: steveo314  it would be soo great if you could put me somethig togheter to give me a hint/example. i'm coplete lost ;-)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a spoon feeding site.  I will give you some hints though.  First, do one thing at a time.  Second, start with simple things even if they are not exactly what you need.  In this case, you might want to start by generating a javascript alert when you tab out of a text field.

Comment: Checking for the blur event would be better than checking for the tab key since the tab key is not the only way to focus on the next input field.